# Installer for windows service without asking for credentials

Tags: c#, windows, service

I developed a Windows Service for a client and created an installer with Install Shield.  I created and configured the installer class within the service. The problem is that during the installation it asks the credentials. Is it possible to avoid this?

Comment: What have you set the `Account` on the service to?

Comment: Please clarify.  Do you mean that when you run the installer it asks for administrative permission to run?  Or that it asks for the username and password to use when running the service?

Answer (score 1):

serviceProcessInstaller will be a property of your projectInstaller - you can set the account on this

```
serviceProcessInstaller.Username = "Username";
serviceProcessInstaller.Password = "Password";
serviceProcessInstaller.Account = ServiceAccount.User;
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I don't believe this is possible, but you might be able to do it within the installer.  I've played with it before but can't remember if I ever got it working.  See [Installing service without admin rights](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22114417/installing-service-without-admin-rights)

checking here might help: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3990/Simple-Windows-Service-Sample

There's a line (after Using the Code, labeled Tip) about setting the Account to LocalSystem, which if my memory serves reminds me of something I may have done to get it to work.